# Spell Checker in Web Application

Tags: asp.net

Currently I am developing website in asp.net.

I wanted to include spellchecker module into my code.

It may not be fare to ask like this, but I don't have enough time to do R&D on that topic, of course I did enough study but I am unable to get the exact way to implement spell checker in my application.

Can any one suggest me how to implement spell checker and where to get source code.

Thank You.

Comment: you should at least tried to google "javascript spell check" or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

op said:

> It may not be fare to ask like this,
>   but I don't have enough time to do R&D
>   on that topic

and then commented:

> Actually I am new to .net. Recently I
>   joined as a .net trainee. My trainer
>   wants me to develop this module.

wow, you're making great strides!

follow the links, should do what you want...

http://forums.karamasoft.com/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=3614

Answer (score 3):

All modern browsers come with built-in spell checkers these days, and users can customise them to their own language, locale and even add new words. Don't bother trying to implement your own. If your IE6 users complain, tell them to upgrade.

Comment: @nani - Then surely you should start building one rather than just asking for links to a free one.

Comment: @nani - one of the skills you'll have to learn is knowing when not to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript and jQuery, the [spellayt plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/spellayt) provides spell checking in IE browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this appliation, following the link -http://www.spellchecker.net/ If you use FCK/CK Editor or TinyMCE, it perfectly works as a plug-in there. if not, you can embed it into your application as a SpellAsYouType functionality or spell-checking in pop-up..